# Differences prepend and prependTo. jQuery

Tags: jquery

I really not understan differences and using `prepend` and `prependTo`.
Here is my code

HTML

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>There</p>
```

jQuery

```
var someText = ' Again ';
$('p:first').prependTo(' ' + someText);
```

but it's not executing.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tuxsanov/UKS7F/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is the order, with `prepend` the element to prepend to comes first

```
var element = $('<div />')
$('p:first').prepend(element);
```

while `prependTo` has the element to prependTo last

```
var element = $('<div />')
element.prependTo($('p:first'));
```

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)

> The `.prepend()` and `.prependTo()` methods perform the same task.
>   The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target.
>   With .prepend(), the selector expression
>   preceding the method is the container into which the content is
>   inserted.
>   With .prependTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes
>   the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on
>   the fly, and it is inserted into the target container.

It's mostly useful for chaining as both methods will return the element the method is applied to, not the element prepended.

Comment: `(' ' + someText)` what's this..? !! Does a string contains a function called .prependTo() ..?  http://jsfiddle.net/UKS7F/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's really just for chaining.

`x.prependTo(y)`

Will prepend x to y and return the original collection x.

`y.prepend(x)`

will also prepend x to y but will return the original collection y.

Answer (score 0):

The is main difference of syntax, see below

```
$('.box').prepend("<div class='newbox'>I'm new box by prepend</div>");
```

and

```
$("<div class='newbox'>I'm new box by prependTo</div>").prependTo('.box');
```

For more details see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-prepend-and-prependto-example/)

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UKS7F/11/), here you need to wrap text in some html element. I have wrapped it in a span

Answer (score 0):

both used to append text or element to another element

```
 var someText = ' Again ';
    $('p:first').prepend(' ' + someText);
```

or you can try this

```
var someText = ' Again ';
(' ' + someText).prependTo($('p:first'));
```